# efficient way to work with ~2k variables of size ~400x400x3

Tags: matlab, optimization, save, load

I am running an optimization algorithm that involves iterating over ~2k variables, each variable representing an image of size ~400x400x3. In my iterations, I need to load these variables, update them, and go back to the next round, something like this

```
% Initialize the global variable x
x = 0;
for iter=1:100
  % Initialize var1 and var2 sum
  var1_sum = 0;
  var2_sum = 0;
  % Save a copy of the global variable x for convergence checks
  x_old = x;
  for var_no=1:1225
    % Load var1_i
    load(['var1_', num2str(var_no), '.mat');
    % Load var2_i
    load(['var2_', num2str(var_no), '.mat');
    % compute var1 sum and var2 sum
    var1_sum = var1_sum + var1_i;
    var2_sum = var2_sum + var2_i;
    % Update var1_i, var2_i
    var1_i = update_var1_using_x(var1_i, x);
    var2_i = update_var2_using_x(var2_i, x);
    % Save them again
    save(['var1_', num2str(var_no), '.mat', var1_i, '-v7.3');
    save(['var2_', num2str(var_no), '.mat', var2_i, '-v7.3');
  end
  % Update x now
  x = x + var1_sum + var2_sum;
  % check is x has been converged
  delta_x = norm(x, 'fro') - norm(x_old, 'fro');
  if(delta_x < 0.0001)
    break;
  end
end
```

As it can be expected, my code is extremely time consuming, and the size and their no. being very large, I cannot keep them in RAM. Can somebody please help me out and suggest me an efficient way to carry this? It has become a huge bottleneck in my run time. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello, sorry I missed adding that changing the inner loop to parfor(as all the variables are independent) alleviates the problem to an extent, but still very time consuming due to the load/save operations

Comment: add `clear` at the end of the loop. It will not save time, but will free the RAM.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. @liliscent

Yes, I have to load and save them in every inner loop. That's the main problem I am facing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response @Adiel

Sorry, as for gaining some performance, I have been using parfor in the inner loop. So, I cannot use the `clear` command.

Comment: you can still `clear var1_i var2_i` inside the inner loop

Comment: Dear @Adiel, 

Apologies if I am misunderstanding your suggestion. Inside a parfor loop, `clear` command violates the needed transparency. It generates
this error **Transparency violation error**. One can see a similar problem reported by the code analyzer itself. 

Thanks again!

Comment: ok, I see. I thought that clearing a specific variable will be ok. But the code analyzer indicates a transparency problem also on `save` inside a parfor

Comment: What about `matfile`? I don't know what the `update_var` function do, but it may work with that

Comment: Are your variables inter-dependent each iteration? It's not clear from your example, but if the variables are independent then you should load each one, do all of the iterations, save it and move on. In essence, have your `for` loops the other way around.

Comment: Hi @Adiel, yes, I have already explored that option, but it didn't really seem to help. Eventually, there is no net performance gain.

Comment: This should more threat the RAM problem, not the performance

Comment: Hi @Wolfie, thanks for your response. No, that's a major hurdle, the variables are not inter-dependent, or rather I should say, there is no clear defined function mapping. The update_var1/2 functions are a bit complicated (say for instance, _min(|var|, theta)_

I have explored that option before as it definitely removes the loading/saving operations, but I was unfortunate to not figure out any explicit mapping.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Adiel, I can definitely try that again, but the last time I implemented that, somehow I did not see any gain in performance. Maybe, as you mentioned, RAM consumption may slow down the parpool workers, which may affect the performance in overall. But, I have no concrete way to enforce this reasoning. I can check again though, Thanks again!

Comment: Your problem is then the parfor. If you load/save in a parfor, it is quite likely the code is slower than with a normal for. Parfors are fast for maths, but *very* slow for data saving and loading

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri. I actually checked this the very first time I implemented this code. I do not have a lot of experience with parfor, but it actually did save me some time. With for, one outer loop iteration took about ~30mins (the code shown above is just a small representation, I have multiple but independent w.r.t. var1/2_i operations in the inner loop), while using parfor, it improved the run time to ~12-14 mins. The major limitation, in my understanding, is still the load/save operations, as I see an incredible boost (and ofocurse, an incorrect solution) if I remove the two operations.

Comment: Your for loops seem counter intuitive. Why don't you loop first over images, and then over iterations? You are now doing `var_no*iter*4` load/save operations. If you loop over `var_no`, load, do all the `iter` and then save, you only need to use `var_no*4` load/save. You do 100 times less

Comment: Dear @AnderBiguri, sorry I couldn't clear the problem enough. My algorithm is actually an optimization algorithm. After the inner loop completes, I optimize the global variable (say x) using the inner loop variables var1/2_i. So, in the next round, the update_var1/2 functions actually take in the new value of x, and update these variables. If you are familiar with ADMM, then I am running ADMM optimization with global consensus problem (i.e. the ~2k local variables var1/2_i need to be be in consensus with the global variable x, and this is carried using ADMM. I can share further details. Thanks

Comment: @AAshish you **need** to share more details or we will be forever bouncing  information because you did not explain the real problem

Comment: Dear @AnderBiguri, I will be happy to share the details and my code. Would you mind sharing me your email, perhaps we can discuss the problem over emails if you don't mind?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, share them in the question.

Comment: Dear @AnderBiguri, I have tried to amend the code so that it can explain my intention. Thanks again for your help.